# Unexpected token on like breaks (smarty + ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, smarty

I need to output a couple of lines of escaped html using ajax, with the object being generated by smarty.
However, I keep getting unexpected token even if I used both nl2br and

```
|regex_replace:'/[\r\n]/' : '<br/>'.
```

Here is the troublesome code:

```
"value":            "&lt;div class=&quot;ps-header-links&quot;&gt;<br/>     <br/>       &lt;ul&gt;<br/>                         &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://prestashop.com&quot; title=&quot;some title&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;icon-small helpicon&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;English&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br/>                         &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;dsjfsiodf&quot; title=&quot;link2title&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;icon-small helpicon&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;Link 2&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br/>                  &lt;/ul&gt; <br/>   &lt;/div&gt;",
```

And here is what I used on the smarty template:

```
"value":            "{$data.value|addslashes|regex_replace:'/[\r\n]/' : '<br/>'}",
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? The original html(escaped using htmlspecialchars as I only need a visual representation):

```
                                                                                            : &lt;div class="ps-header-links"&gt;

    &lt;ul&gt;
                        &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="http://prestashop.com" title="some title"&gt;&lt;span class="icon-small helpicon"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;English&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
                        &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="dsjfsiodf" title="link2title"&gt;&lt;span class="icon-small helpicon"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;Link 2&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
                &lt;/ul&gt; 
&lt;/div&gt;
```

the full error

```
    textStatus: 'parsererror'
errorThrown: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token     '
responseText:
{
"products": [
{
    "id":            1,
    "link":          "http://localhost/presta156/index.php?    id_product=1&controller=product&id_lang=1#/color-black/disk_space-16gb",
    "quantity":      4,
    "priceByLine":   "765,04 €",
    "name":          "iPod Nano",
    "price":         "765,04 €",
    "price_float":   "632.28",
    "idCombination": 18,
    "idAddressDelivery": 2,
    "is_gift" : 0,
    "hasAttributes": true,
    "attributes":    "Black, 16GB",
    "hasCustomizedDatas": true,
    "customizedDatas":[
            {

        "customizationId":  19,
        "quantity":         "1",
        "datas": [
                            {
                "type": "1",
                "datas":
                [
                                        {
                    "index":            0,
                    "value":            "&lt;div class=&quot;ps-header-links&quot;&gt;&lt;br/&gt;       &lt;br/&gt;     &lt;ul&gt;&lt;br/&gt;                           &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://prestashop.com&quot; title=&quot;some title&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;icon-small helpicon&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;English&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;br/&gt;                           &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;dsjfsiodf&quot; title=&quot;link2title&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;icon-small helpicon&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;Link 2&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;br/&gt;                    &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;br/&gt; &lt;/div&gt;",
                    "truncatedValue":   "&lt;div..."
                    }                   ]
            }                           ]
    }                       ]
}],
"discounts": [
],
"shippingCost": "2,42 €",
"shippingCostFloat": "2.42",
"wrappingCost": "0,00 €",
"nbTotalProducts": "4",
"total": "767,46 €",
"productTotal": "765,04 €",
"hasError" : false
}
```

FUrther info:
It seems the error only occurs when the html is indented. Single spaces are okay, but tabs cause the issue. Any way I can strip them off on smarty? I tried {strip}, replace ' ' : '' but they don't work!

FIXED: I escaped tabs using |regex_replace:"/[\t]/":" "

Comment: What is complaining about unexpected tokens? Does `|regex_replace:'/[\r\n]/' : '&lt;br/&gt;'` help?

Comment: It doesn't help either, unfortunatey! added the full error above

Comment: Maybe it's the whitespace around the last `:`, try `|regex_replace:'/[\r\n]/':'<br/>'`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, it's still the same. The single quote with trailing space is nowhere to be found, I'm clueless